# Are the two statements equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $X$ be any non-empty set

Let $Y$ be any non-empty set

Let $P(m,n)$ be any propositional statement containing object $m \in X$ and $n \in Y$

$[\forall\ m \in X,\forall\ n \in Y] [P(m,n)] \tag 1$

$[m \in X\ \wedge\ n \in Y] \Rightarrow [P(m,n)] \tag 2$

**Is $(1)$ and $(2)$ logically equivalent? Why? Why not?**

**In other words, is $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$?**

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Comment: In the second one the universal quantifiers are missing: are they implicitly assumed?

Comment: But yes, in general, $\forall x \in M (Px)$ is $\forall x (x \in M \to Px)$

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA: can you please give a reference to that formula in a book or article?

Comment: Why is there a need for universal quantifier in my second statement? I need to get some  education on these basics. Can you refer a book?

Comment: If we do not assume that a formula with $x$ free like $(x=0)$ is implicitly universally quantified, then it is not true that it is equivalent to $\forall x (x=0)$.

Comment: can you please give a reference to that formula in a book or article regarding such information?

Comment: See [Bounded quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier)

Comment: Ad yes, $[∀m∈X,∀n∈Y]P(m,n)$ means $\forall m \forall n [(m \in X \land n \in Y) \to P(m,n)]$

Answer (score 2):

I wish to to take up the question in a broader setting not limited to mathematics. The divergence between two formulas can be discussed from the point of the contrast between open formula/closed formula. I think the role of open formulas deserves more attention than usually has been devoted.

For the discussion I intend to set out, it may be helpful to skim over the Wikipedia article [*De dicto* and *de re*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_dicto_and_de_re). Let us consider an example from the article (with a minor modification to facilitate comparison):

> Peter believes someone is in the vicinity of his home to get him.

We may discern two readings of the sentence:

(1) On an unquantified reading, what we can say true is Peter's fear described by the predicate '*. . . is in the vicinity of his home to get him*'. The indefinite pronoun 'someone' occurs with a generic semantic value; not only that there is no information about the identity of the perpetrator(s), but also it could be anybody or everybody, perhaps nobody. It is more a linguistic placeholder in the description than a variable that represents the elements of a set. We may make better sense of this reading if we imagine Peter suspectedly as a paranoid personality. We may denote 'someone' by $x$ and the description by $\phi$, thus partially symbolise the sentence as

> Peter believes $\phi(x)$.

In this sentence, $\phi(x)$ is an intensional expression not connected to an extension. The quantifiers bound the expression to an extension (in first-order logic, to first-order entities).

(2) On a quantified reading, the indefinite pronoun 'someone' occurs with a specific semantic value; we are still not given information about the identity of the perpetrator(s), hence grammatically still indefinite. But it is connected to at least one real person from the domain of the current discourse (i.e., people in the vicinity of Peter's home). In this sense, the description has turned into some information about identity. We can express this case as

> Peter believes $\exists x\phi(x)$.

or

> Peter believes $\forall x\phi(x)$.

In these sentences, $\phi(x)$ is an extensional expression, for the quantifiers bound the expression to an extension (in first-order logic, to first-order entities) make it be truth-apt.

In this perspective, the formulas in the question are not equivalent (otherwise, we would drop universal quantifiers like we do for brackets whenever there is no risk of ambiguity).

In another perspective, there is a convention to treat open formulas as universally quantified. But this is a convention *about* logic, not *in and of* logic. So, for example, transitivity of a relation $R$ is expressed as $R(x, y)\wedge R(y, z)\rightarrow (x, z)$ instead of $\forall x\forall y\forall z(R(x, y)\wedge R(y, z)\rightarrow (x, z))$. This convention is also followed in the procedures after the existential quantifiers are eliminated by Skolemisation.

---

Addendum

Alonzo Church states a fine observation that could be complimentary to the foregoing discussion in his *[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://ntroduction%20to%20mathematical%20logic)* (p. 40, the italics in the original):

> Variables thus having occurrences in a constant or form which are not
> occurrences as free variables of it are called *bound variables* of
> the constant or form. The difference is that a form containing a
> particular variable, say *x*, as a *free variable* has values for
> various values of the variable, but a constant or form which contains
> *x* as a *bound variable only* has a meaning which is independent of *x*—not in the sense of having the same value for every value of *x*, but in the sense that the assignment of particular values to *x* is
> not a relevant procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the lengthy answer... Can you please give your email for some discussion with you on propositional logic?

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can contact me on [academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/).

Comment: Sir, I have send you a message in academia.edu Please read it.

Answer (score -1):

Since you assumed that m,n are arbitrary, once you’ve actually derived something you can use the Universal Quantifier because arbitrary names/sets allow you to make statements/inferences without loss of generality (WLOG).

For example, suppose you assume that some predicate “F” holds for an arbitrary name “a”, i.e. Fa. Suppose you derive Gb within the scope of your assumption that Fa. Note that G is just some predicate and b is a name that doesn’t occur anywhere in another assumption that hasn’t already been discharged. Since you derived Gb WLOG, you may discharge your assumption and derive Fa->Fb, which implies ∀x∀y(Fx->Gy).

Still, the two formulae you provided are not equivalent unless you’ve actually derived the unquantified one WLOG.